# How can I send a message to a specific channel by using my own "say" command in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to make a code like I write  .say blabla" in another channel and It will delete my channel and send my message to "#general" but I can't find a code to do this.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ç')) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        message.delete()
        const SayMessage = message.content.slice(2).trim();
        message.channel.send(SayMessage)
```

Here is the code. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `message.delete()` first and then after that, you are doing `message.content`. In this case, the `message.content` will be null and you cant send an empty message. So first assign the message content to `SayMessage` and then delete the message.
Also if you need to send to another specific channel, you need to get the channel, and then send it there.

Eg:

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ç')) {
        const SayMessage = message.content.slice(2).trim();
        message.delete();
        const Mchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('the-channel-id');
        Mchannel.send(SayMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me but also i used that code instead of Mchannel:
```
client.channels.cache.get('channel-id').send(SayMessage)
```
That worked too.

Comment: Glad to help you.